# Meta data implementation Using Asp.net and C# In SAML 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml

I've created an application for single singn on service(SSO).

I am using IDP and a ServiceProvider.

In the IDP(Identity provider)I am using

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(created Xml oject );
```

to write the metadata xml .

I want know, how the target website service provider fetches this metadada?
and how can I handle SingleLogoutService ?

I am using ASP.net and C#.

Comment: According to [specification](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35391/sstc-saml-metadata-errata-2.0-wd-04-diff.pdf) you can literally put it in a known location for IdP and SP.